# Split a column by group

Tags: r, split, dataframe

My data set is like this:

```
tweet_created_at                              hashtag_text
2015-05-08 05:45:30                           farinaz,farkhunda,ozgecanaslan
2015-05-08 06:01:24                           ozgecanaslan,sendeanlat
2015-05-08 09:51:35                           ozgecanaslan,genclikyasaklanamaz
```

I need to convert my data set to this:

```
tweet_created_at                              hashtag_text
2015-05-08 05:45:30                           farinaz
2015-05-08 05:45:30                           farkhunda
2015-05-08 05:45:30                           ozgecanaslan
2015-05-08 06:01:24                           ozgecanaslan
2015-05-08 06:01:24                           sendeanlat
2015-05-08 09:51:35                           ozgecanaslan
2015-05-08 09:51:35                           genclikyasaklanamaz
```

I assume that I can use some sapply for this but I couldn't figure out doing this with repeating tweet_created_at column.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your notice and this is exactly same question with same solution. I tried to delete it but I don't have permission for this :(

Comment: You don't need to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `cSplit` from `library(splitstackshape)`.  We specify the `sep` as `,`   `direction` as 'long' and the `splitCols` as 'hash_tag_text' to split the column and reshape the dataset to 'long' format.

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 cSplit(df1, 'hashtag_text', ',', 'long')
 #      tweet_created_at        hashtag_text
 #1: 2015-05-08 05:45:30             farinaz
 #2: 2015-05-08 05:45:30           farkhunda
 #3: 2015-05-08 05:45:30        ozgecanaslan
 #4: 2015-05-08 06:01:24        ozgecanaslan
 #5: 2015-05-08 06:01:24          sendeanlat
 #6: 2015-05-08 09:51:35        ozgecanaslan
 #7: 2015-05-08 09:51:35 genclikyasaklanamaz
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(tweet_created_at = c("2015-05-08 05:45:30", 
 "2015-05-08 06:01:24", 
 "2015-05-08 09:51:35"), hashtag_text =   
 c("farinaz,farkhunda,ozgecanaslan", 
 "ozgecanaslan,sendeanlat", "ozgecanaslan,genclikyasaklanamaz"
 )), .Names = c("tweet_created_at", "hashtag_text"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, it is giving same row numbers with original data set. My original data set has 2274 obs. and after use this script the result is same.

Comment: @eabanoz I was just copy/pasting the example you showed to get the expected output.

Comment: @eabanoz I tried your dput example.  It gives the long format.  Earlier I think the argument order was the problem.  Can you try it now?

Comment: Hi akrun, it works and thanks

Comment: @eabanoz Thanks for commenting.  I also had the same problem after I changed the order.  Looks like order of arguments are important.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Womens.Rights)[,c(hashtag_text=strsplit(hashtag_text,split=",")),
                     by=tweet_created_at]
      tweet_created_at        hashtag_text
1: 2015-05-08_05:45:30             farinaz
2: 2015-05-08_05:45:30           farkhunda
3: 2015-05-08_05:45:30        ozgecanaslan
4: 2015-05-08_06:01:24        ozgecanaslan
5: 2015-05-08_06:01:24          sendeanlat
6: 2015-05-08_09:51:35        ozgecanaslan
7: 2015-05-08_09:51:35 genclikyasaklanamaz
```

(Note: I added underscores to the times manually to let `read.table` read in your data)

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your help and this script is giving this error message    :Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(Womens.Rights), , strsplit(hashtag_text,  : 
  j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group.  (Womens.Rights is my date set name)

Comment: @eabanoz you've got `by=tweet_created_at`, right? what version of `data.table` do you have installed... maybe this is some new behavior.

Comment: does this work? `setDT(Womens.Rights)[,strsplit(hashtag_text,split=","),by=tweet_created_at]`

Comment: I used it in the same format by=tweet_created_at and my data.table version is 1.9.4 and it is working under R version 3.2.1.

Comment: Maybe the class of `hashtag_text` is wrong. Can you put the output of `dput(head(Womens.Rights))` into your question?

Comment: structure(list(tweet_created_at = structure(c(1431070647, 1431068077, 
1431070163, 1431078330, 1431079284, 1431082640), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), hashtag_text = c("ferinazxosrewani,ozgecanaslan", 
"ozgecanaslan,sendeanlat", "ozgecanaslan", "farinaz,farkhunda,ozgecanaslan", 
"ozgecanaslan,sendeanlat", "ozgecanaslan")), .Names = c("tweet_created_at", 
"hashtag_text"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001b0788>)

Comment: So does it work or not?

Comment: Strange. My code still works exactly on your `structure`. This doesn't work: `setDT(Womens.Rights)[,strsplit(hashtag_text,split=","),by=tweet_created_at]`?

Comment: Michael, it works and thanks.